# Is it a bad practice to set focus programatically to controls that's earlier in the reading order because the focused element has to be disabled?

Tags: accessibility

There are two buttons 'Show Less' and 'Show More'. I cannot use toggle buttons here because there is a middle state(displays one line of content by default) in the default view. 
Let's say a user tabs to 'Show more' and activates the button, the section below expands and Show more button gets disabled. 
When user selects one of[image] the buttons, is it reasonable to set focus to opposite buttons button even if it's one step backwards in the reading order(for example Show Less is before Show More).

Comment: What is the reason to disable button? If there nothing "more" to show... just didn't do anything when user is click it.

Answer (score 2):

From an accessibility perspective, you normally don't want to move the focus off a button after it's been selected, but when a button becomes disabled after selecting it, you'd be ok moving the focus to the previous button.  You *could* leave the focus where it is and the screen reader would announce that the button is no longer active, but that can sometimes cause another accessibility issue if the focus indicator disappears because the element became inactive ([2.4.7 - Focus Visible](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-focus-visible.html)).